# Check Decimal value is Zero in RDLC

Tags: rdlc

I want to check whether a sum of decimal values equal to zero in RDLC. I tried

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!JanuaryValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")=0,"0.00","F")
```

and

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!JanuaryValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")=CDec("0.00"),"0.00","F")
```

In both expressions, the result is "F". What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!JanuaryValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet") > 0, "F", "0.00")
```

Instead of looking for a zero, you are looking for a value greater than what you want, eliminating the need for the correct format.

You should also change the data in the DataTable to decimal.

Here's a similar problem: [RDLC report doesn't detect NULL values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276648/rdlc-report-doesnt-detect-null-values-correctly)