# VB.NET string equals ".abc" or ".xyz" else

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, text

How do I check for two possible strings else... (see example code)

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Input path.
        Dim p As String = TextBox1.Text
        ' Get extension.
        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(p)

        If extension = ".abc" Or ".xyz" Then
            'nothing
            Label1.Text = "file type suported"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Unsuported file type"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: extension = ".abc" Or extension = ".xyz"

Comment: why don't u use a switch case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim Schmelter has already answered this quite thoroughly but:-

A Simple alternative is a `Select` statement - this will make it easier to update your code if you decide to support some other file type in the future:

```
Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(p)
Select Case extension
Case ".abc", ".xyz"
    Label1.Text = "file type suported"
Case Else
    Label1.Text = "unsupported file type"
End Select
```

Comment: I would even keep the list of allowed extensions in a config file (comma separated or so), so that you don't have to recompile each time you add one.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the condition:

```
If extension = ".abc" OrElse extension = ".xyz" Then
    'nothing
        Label1.Text = "file type suported"
Else
    Label1.Text = "Unsuported file type"
End If
```

I have used `OrElse` because this checks the second condition only if the first condition returned false. For the same reason you should normally use `AndAlso` instead of `And`.

Consider this example:

```
Dim extension As String = Nothing
If extension Is Nothing Or extension.ToLower() = ".abc"
' ...
```

This throws an exception because `extension` is nothing but the `Or` causes the second condition to be evaluated anyway. This is safe:

```
If extension Is Nothing OrElse extension.ToLower() = ".abc"
```

[Or versus OrElse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse)

Another aproach is to use a positive-list and `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
Dim allowedExtensions = { ".abc", ".xyz" }
If allowedExtensions.Contains(extension) Then
    ' ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also put your supported extensions in a string

```
Dim ValidExtensions As String = ".abc.xyz"
```

Then

```
If ValidExtensions.Contains(extension) Then
        Label1.Text = "file type suported"
Else
    Label1.Text = "Unsuported file type"
End If
```

This way it won't matter how many extensions you support or what changes you make to the list you only change the main string for the code to work.

Plus down the road if you decide to let the user change the supported file types you can make the changes programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If extension = ".abc" Or extension = ".xyz" Then
```

Comment: I'd guess the downvote was because you're using `Or` instead of `OrElse`, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want alter one line to this:

```
If extension = ".abc" Or extension = ".xyz" Then
```

Comment: Orelse is usually a better choice than Or

Comment: Take your word for it - it's been a long time since I did any VB.net. Still the main point was the missing variable name.

Comment: Orelse translates to || in c#. Or translates to |. Orelse makes sure the second part isn't evaluated if the first part already is true.

Answer (score 0):

Store all the supported extensions in a `HashSet<string>` structure and use the `Contains` method to check whether a specified extension is supported or not.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim supportedExtensions As New System.Collections.Generic.HashSet(Of String)
        supportedExtensions.Add(".abc")
        supportedExtensions.Add(".xyz")

        ' Input path.
        Dim p As String = TextBox1.Text
        ' Get extension.
        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(p)

        If (supportedExtensions.Contains(extension)) Then
            'nothing
            Label1.Text = "file type suported"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Unsuported file type"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**UPDATE:** As the number of supported extensions is increased, the OR conditions needed for extension support checking would go up and this would affect the legibility and maintainability of your code. Consequently, this code snippet offers you more readability.

Comment: Although this works, it doesn't give any benefit over using `If a Or b Then` and just overcomplicates a simple question

Comment: I don't agree with you. Having multiple OR conditions in a statement decreases code readability and it's not considered as "clean code". What if the supported extensions go beyond 10? Is 10 OR conditions in a statement readable? and Is it of high maintainability?