# How do I get around the error: Conversion from string "alan" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am just a Yr 10 programming student. The error is: `Conversion from string "alan" to type 'Boolean' is not valid`. I can never get around it. The error is on the line where it says `(If firstname = "alan" Or "Alan" Then)`. Here is the code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim firstname As String
    Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to Alan's Computer: Press enter to continue")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name")
    firstname = Console.ReadLine()
    If firstname = "alan" Or "Alan" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome")

    Else
        Console.WriteLine("You may not enter {0}", firstname)
    End If

End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
If firstname = "alan" OrElse firstname = "Alan" Then
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("You may not enter {0}", firstname)
End If
```

You need to repeat the expression `firstname = <value>` for the two cases, but you need also to replace the Or with the more appropriate [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)

See [Or vs OrElse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse)

Comment: I  tried changing the code to this and it did not work. The same error appeared

Comment: Conversion from string "alan" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: I have tried just in case and this could not happen with the code above. Are you sure that you have typed correctly the IF line?