# Or Operator in If Else Statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

I have a question and hope someone can help me here.

If I use an or operater in an if else statement as

```
If Date.Now.Month > 3 OR UserID < 100 then
...
Else
...
End If
```

does the code brakes at >3 and doesent consider <100 if we have a month = 2 e.g. then there would be no constant else statement. Or how can I interpret the If statement here?

Comment: What do you mean by "which cases"? It's just "if the condition is false"...

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If everything in the `if` part is true, the code there will be executed. Otherwise, whatever is in the `else` will be executed.

Comment: Note that you should get used to use `OrElse` (and `AndAlso`) instead of `Or` (and `And`). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be your If statement inverted, so:

```
Date.Now.Month <= 3 AND UserID >= 100
```

Comment: +1 for applying De Morgan's laws without compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have the following case: 
`Date.Now.Month <= 3 AND UserId >= 100`