# VB.net Combobox or Textbox null or empty

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

For some reason the below query doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone advise why it is behaving different to what I expect.

Basically if the combobox.text or textbox.text stated are both blank then a message should show.  If one of them are selected then present the current datetime.

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbx_Aux_Codes.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(com_Work_Item.Text) Then

    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Task or Work Item")

Else

    StartTime = DateTimeLog()
    MessageBox.Show(StartTime)

End If
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

change `OrElse` to `AndAlso`

Your code should look like this

```
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbx_Aux_Codes.Text) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(com_Work_Item.Text) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Task or Work Item")
  Else
      StartTime = DateTimeLog()
      MessageBox.Show(StartTime)
  End If
```

`OrElse` or `Or` will return `true` if one is true so if you want that message to pop only when both are empty, since you want to proceed with else if one is filled, then use `And` instead.

Comment: Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`

Comment: @MattWilko please edit my answer. I don't want to take the credit. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to use AndAlso for this requirement. OrElse serves a different "short-circuiting" purpose. You may check this out: [Or versus OrElse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse) and use an ElseIf for your second criteria:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbx_Aux_Codes.Text) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(com_Work_Item.Text) Then

MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Task or Work Item")

ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(lbx_Aux_Codes.Text) Or _
String.IsNullOrEmpty(com_Work_Item.Text) Then

StartTime = DateTimeLog()
MessageBox.Show(StartTime)

End If
```

Comment: this is confusing as it is nothing to do with Or vs OrElse

Comment: AndAlso is also a short circuit evaluator which is not clear from your first two lines.

Comment: I did not want to turn this into a discussion sir, but there is nothing in my answer which says that AndAlso is not a short circuit evaluator.