# Scalar Query: Object Reference

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple function that I use to return a value. This is the logic to return a string.

```
If cmdx.ExecuteScalar Is DBNull.Value Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdx.ExecuteScalar.ToString) Then
    Return String.Empty

Else
    Return cmdx.ExecuteScalar
End If
```

However the first line is returning this error: Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The error appears to be somewhat sporadic.

Perhaps this is a better way to handle the returned values and possible `Nulls`?

```
If cmdx.ExecuteScalar Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return String.Empty
Else
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdx.ExecuteScalar) Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return cmdx.ExecuteScalar
        End If
End If
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: You probably want `OrElse`. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse). And I would use `Is Nothing` rather than `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider that [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could return Nothing if there is no match to the cmd query (or DBNull.Value if the match contains the NULL value). If you use directly the return of ExecuteScalar without testing for Nothing you could end up with the infamous Null Reference Exception

So better use it in this way (and avoid two calls to ExecuteScalar)

```
Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar
if result is Nothing OrElse 
   result = DBNull.Value OrElse 
   string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString) then
     .....
else
     ....
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take is to use the **?** Null/Nothing check since VB14.

```
Dim result as object = cmd.ExecuteScalar
If o Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(o?.ToString) Then
   ...
Else
   ...
End If
```