# ASP. NET Error: XML literal cannot appear here unless it is enclosed in parentheses

Tags: asp.net, xml, webmatrix

I am attempting to port some old asp to asp.net. Following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228211(v=vs.100).aspx)! I am going through the errors and this XML one has me stuck. I have placed the opening and closing parenthesis in several places, but I am still getting the error. I'm sure this is something I'm overlooking, so any help is welcomed.

```
IF AAP><"" or EXECCOMM><"" or Immigration><"" or MgrMember><"" or OSHA><"" or StratPlan><"" or WageHour><"" or ERISA><"" or Health><"" or Litig><"" or OffHead><"" or PICCOMM><"" or Traditional><"" or WorkComp><""  then
   BodyText=Replace(BodyText, "@@@SPECEmail@@@", "<b>Special E-mail Groups: </b>")
```

Comment: What is `><` operator?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You could have been kind and written that the the "not equal to" operator in VB.NET is `<>` ;)

Comment: @Andrew Not an expert in VB.NET so couldn't say and language wasn't specified and there was some mention of XML so a bit vague. But I could've guessed, sure. Might still not be enough

Comment: I recommend that you use [`OrElse`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1170790/1115360) in place of `Or` in that statement - it can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [FAQ entry on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531378(v=vs.90).aspx):

> An XML literal declaration is used in an expression in a location that
>   is ambiguous to the Visual Basic compiler. That is, the Visual Basic
>   compiler cannot determine whether the less-than character (<) is
>   intended as a comparative operator or the start of an XML literal.

You have a lot of `<` and `>` characters in your statement and that confuses the compiler.

Also: `><` needs to be `<>` as explained in the comment by [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton).

So try changing your code to:

```
IF (AAP<>"") OR (EXECCOMM<>"") OR (Immigration<>"") OR (MgrMember<>"") OR (OSHA<>"") OR (StratPlan<>"") OR (WageHour<>"") OR (ERISA<>"") OR (Health<>"") OR (Litig<>"") OR (OffHead<>"") OR (PICCOMM<>"") OR (Traditional<>"") OR (WorkComp<>"")  THEN
    BodyText=Replace(BodyText, "@@@SPECEmail@@@", "<b>Special E-mail Groups: </b>")
```

Comment: The `><` need to be `<>`. Ref: [Comparison Operators (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx). Incidentally, my copy of VS2015 (or maybe one off the extensions in it) autocorrrects that.

Comment: OK, I haven't written any VB since 1996, so I didn't know, but I adapted my answer.