# I can not figure out how to delete these images using my code

Tags: vb.net

I am checking images for width and height and trying to delete all that are not satisfying the if requirement. The If requirement works (from 12 -> 1) and i can not use f.delete in this case as it throws out an error "f is in use by another program; can not open image10.jpg" (12 and 11 do not satisfy the If requirement, 10 does).

How do i delete images that satisfy the If requirement?

```
Dim s As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\*\source\repos\CinemaSpider\CinemaSpider\bin\Debug")
Dim files As FileInfo() = s.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        For Each f As FileInfo In files
           Dim bmp As New Bitmap(f.FullName)
           If bmp.Width.ToString() < 182 Or bmp.Height.ToString() < 268 Then
              f.Delete()
           End If
```

Comment: You need to `Dispose()` your bitmap

Comment: Also, get rid of the .ToString, height and width are numbers.

Comment: Another option is look into [Image.GetPropertyItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getpropertyitem?view=netframework-4.7.2). Basically right click on the file and then select "Details", what you see there can be pulled out by using `GetPropertyItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dispose the reference to the image before trying to delete it. Best way is to use `using`:

```
    Dim s As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\*\source\repos\CinemaSpider\CinemaSpider\bin\Debug")
    Dim files As FileInfo() = s.GetFiles("*.jpg")
    For Each f As FileInfo In files
        Dim DoDelete as Boolean= false
        Using  image1 As Image = Image.FromFile(f.FullName)
            If image1.Width < 182 OrElse image1.Height < 268 Then
                DoDelete = True
            End If
        End Using
        if DoDelete Then f.Delete()
    Next
```

Comment: It would be good to show the use of OrElse: [Or versus OrElse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170790/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton User `OrElse` to spare making one comparison? What else you want to achieve with `OrElse` here?

Comment: Obviously it is a tiny thing in this context, but it is a good habit to use it nevertheless. And the OP would get to learn something new as a bonus.

Comment: @CodePope  - I agree with Andrew, always encourage good habits.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different method, using the Shell extensions provided by the `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation` COM library.
You don't need to load a Bitmap and dispose of it to gather the informations you require. These are provided by the Shell.

[All Windows Properties related to Shell Object types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props).

To use the Shell32 namespace, you need to add a reference in your project to this Type Library:
`Project -> References -> COM -> Type Library -> Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation`

```
Imports Shell32

Dim imageFolder As String = "[Insert Your Path]"
Dim shell As New Shell()
Dim items As FolderItems = shell.NameSpace(imageFolder).Items

For Each item As FolderItem2 In items
    If item.ExtendedProperty("Type").ToString().Contains("JPEG") Then
        If CInt(item.ExtendedProperty("System.Image.HorizontalSize")) < 187 OrElse
            CInt(item.ExtendedProperty("System.Image.VerticalSize")) < 268 Then
            File.Delete(item.Path)
        End If
    End If
Next

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items)
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell)
Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()
```