# Can InStr be used to find multiple String1 values?

Tags: excel, vba, instr

I'm manipulating some data, by searching through a list and and printing out the row numbers of the cells that match the criteria I'm looking for. I'm using `InStr` to do this - can this be used to search for multiple items?

I've tried "Or", "And" etc but they don't seem to work, and there are a lot of criteria I'm looking for so would prefer not to have lots of If statements.

```
For Each cell In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "A" or "B") > 0 Then


   'Print row number...

     End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

> Run-time error "13" Type mismatch

occurs with the above. The actual output would be the row number that "A" or "B" occurs in.

Comment: `Or` doesn't work that way. You would need `If InStr(1, cell.Value, "A") > 0 Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "B") > 0 Then`. However, `OrElse` is better than `Or` for that code: [What's the difference between or and OrElse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1170754/1115360)

Comment: You're not writing VB6 code so don't use `InStr` at all.  If you actually care about the index then you should be calling `String.IndexOf` but if all you care about is whether a substring is there then you probably ought to be calling `String.Contains`.  Just be aware that `IndexOf` can be case-sensitive or -insensitive while `Contains` is only case-sensitive.

Comment: Also note that you can use a bit of LINQ to allow you to avoid a long composite condition and thus also support an arbitrary number of values, e.g. `If {"A", "B"}.Any(Function(s) cell.Value.Contains(s)) Then`.  I'm guessing that `cell.Value` is not type `String` though, so you should cast or convert it to that type, i.e. `CStr(cell.Value)` or `cell.Value.ToString()`.  If you have `Option Strivct On`, which you should, then that would be required.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - thanks for this - although that doesn't seem to work in that it gives me a syntax error - any idea why?

Comment: Are you in .NET or are you in Excel and thus programming in VBA?  If the latter, ignore the comment on `OrElse` and also ignore the subsequent advice for solving your problem in .NET.

Comment: @Craig I'm in Excel/VBA - thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton apologies, a mere misclick.

Comment: @user2819098 So it's back to `If InStr(1, cell.Value, "A") > 0 Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "B") > 0 Then` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try addition to shorten your code a bit and also perhaps make it more readable:

```
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "A") + _
   InStr(1, cell.Value, "B") > 0 Then
     'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Hi Ron, this is exactly what I was looking for - thanks! :)