# “Conversion from string ” “ to type 'Double' is not valid” VB

Tags: vba, vb.net

I got this message: *Conversion from string to type Double is not valid* and I can't figure out what to do. Here's the code.

```
    Dim Amount As String = TextBoxAmount.Text

    If Amount = "" Or Not IsNumeric(Amount) Then
        MsgBox("Incorect Format!", InfoOKOnly, AppTitle)
        TextBoxAmount.Focus()
        Return '- Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim DblAmount As Double = CType(Amount, Double)
    If (DblAmount < 500) Then
        MsgBox("Amount must be greater than or equal to 500", InfoOKOnly, AppTitle)
        TextBoxAmount.Focus()
        Return
    End If

    TextBoxAmount.Text = Format(DblAmount, "#,##0.  00")
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    If (MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, AppTitle) = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        If TextBoxAccountNo.Text = "" Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxAccountNo.Text) Or
           TextBoxAccountName.Text = "" Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxAccountName.Text) Or
           TextBoxPhoneNo.Text = "" Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxPhoneNo.Text) Or
           TextBoxAmount.Text = "" Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxAmount.Text) Then
            '--^_^
            Return
        End If

        Dim cf As MyClassFiles1 = New MyClassFiles1()

        Dim accNo As String = TextBoxAccountNo.Text
        Dim accName As String = TextBoxAccountName.Text
        Dim PhoneNo As String = TextBoxPhoneNo.Text
        Dim Cash As Double = CDbl(TextBoxAmount.Text)
```

And the problem is here, in this line of code (first above). When I enter numbers in textbox (amount) it says that cannot be converted to double.

```
        Dim o As MyAccountClass1 = New MyAccountClass1(accNo, accName, PhoneNo, Cash)

        FileOpen(1, cf.GetMasterFile, OpenMode.Append)

        '-- C stand for Create New Account
        WriteLine(1, o.AccountNo, o.AccountName, o.PhoneNo, o.Amount, "Active")

        FileOpen(2, cf.GetTransactionFile, OpenMode.Append)

        WriteLine(2, o.AccountNo, CreatedDate, CreatedTime, "C", o.Amount)

        '--Close before reopening in another mode.

        FileClose(1)
        FileClose(2)

        MsgBox("The files have been saved!", InfoOKOnly, AppTitle)

        ClearTextBoxes()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)

```
    ...
    Dim Cash As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBoxAmount.Text, Cash) Then
        'do sth, show some msgbox that value in the textBox is incorrect
    End If
    ...
```

Also, your checks `String.IsNullOrEmpty` should be replaced with `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` because you check for Empty before it `TextBoxAccountNo.Text = ""`

And one more thing about the code. You want to use `OrElse` instead of `Or`
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170754/or-versus-orelse), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949689/10548234).

Comment: I've done everything you said but the problem is still there :( I don't know what else to do...

Comment: What your error means is that textBox is empty. Are you sure that you take the value from the correct textBox?

Comment: TextBoxAmount.Text = Format(DblAmount, "#,##0.  00") This was the problem (space). Everything is perfect now. Thank you for your time guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line.

```
TextBoxAmount.Text = Format(DblAmount, "#,##0.  00")
```

The spaces between 0. and 00 will not be accepted by a Double.

You can combine your validation in the Save button. Don't insult the user by asking if they want to continue.

Use the System.IO methods avaiable from .net. File.AppendAllText opens, writes to, and closes the file saving you several lines of code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim InputCash As Double

    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBoxAmount.Text, InputCash) OrElse InputCash < 500 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount greater than or equal to 500.")
        TextBoxAmount.Focus()
        Return '- Exit Sub
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxAccountNo.Text) OrElse
       String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxAccountName.Text) OrElse
       String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxPhoneNo.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all boxes.")
        Return
    End If

    Dim cf As MyClassFiles1 = New MyClassFiles1(TextBoxAccountNo.Text, TextBoxAccountName.Text, TextBoxPhoneNo.Text,InputCash)
    Dim message = cf.SaveFiles()
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub

Public Class MyClassFiles1
    Public Property AccountNo As String
    Public Property AccountName As String
    Public Property PhoneNo As String
    Public Property Amount As Double

    Public Sub New(number As String, name As String, pnone As String, cash As Double)
        AccountNo = number
        AccountName = name
        PhoneNo = pnone
        Amount = cash
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMasterFile() As String
        Return "C:\SomeUser\MasterAccountFile.txt"
    End Function

    Private Function GetTransactionFile() As String
        Return "C:\SomeUser\TransactionFile.txt"
    End Function

    Public Function SaveFiles() As String
        Try
            Dim strForMaster = $"{AccountNo},{AccountName},{PhoneNo},{Amount},Active"
            File.AppendAllText(GetMasterFile(), strForMaster)
            Dim strForTransaction = $"{AccountNo},{Now.Date},{Now.ToShortTimeString},C,{Amount}"
            File.AppendAllText(GetTransactionFile(), strForTransaction)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
        Return "The files have been saved!"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You were right. Problem was with a format. I removed space and everything works perfectly fine. Thank you for your time, you helped me a lot! :)